# Steps to Follow for Fixing a Patchy and Weedy New Lawn Which was Planted over several times

Tags: lawn-repair

Trying to grow an organic lawn over the summer months in central CT but have achieved limited success.  Started 2.5 years ago by completely removing all existing weed and lawn. Put down lime and  topsoil then Safer Lawn Restore starter fertilizer and a quality seed mix from local gardening center. Watered several times a day to keep seed damp. Got patchy grass and with it crab grass and clover.  Started over again in some areas and have spent days hand picking out weeds and clover. Then reseeded and same problems again. How do I repair the patchy lawn and keep the weeds at bay. What sequence of steps should I follow? Fertilizer (type), seed, cover with straw or top soil?